# I can't do forecasting on Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, alm

In Team Foundation Server, I have the following sprints created:

[image]

However, on the backlog, I only see Sprint 1, and forecast does not work

[image]

What am I missing to configure here?

Comment: Do you need to tick on multiple sprint in order to get forcase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forecasting module will only forecast selected sprints:

[image]

Comment: thanks!, what does the checkbox is supposed to mean?

Comment: Whether the sprint is active for the selected team.